# Are there any ways to integrate fingerprint biometrics on HTML5 or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this new project that requires fingerprint bio metrics.

A Regular fingerprint scanner device will be used but I have less idea on how to use web technologies(HTML,JS,etc...) with this device, I already know that one way to do this is through Java. I was wondering if it is possible that this could be done using basic web technologies like JavaScript, HTML5 or even PHP.

All I need to do is to save the image of the scanned fingerprint to a specific file but I am not sure if HTML5 or JavaScript alone can do this.

I need to know if this is really possible and how.
Any solutions will do.

Comment: You need to be much more specific. What is the platform for starters?

Comment: That's not a grand response to someone trying to help. Be more specific. What fingerprint scanner? Is there a limitation on programming languages / SDKs that said finger print scanner can accept? Is the fingerprint scanner capable of connecting to the internet or does it need to be connected to an intermediary device. You MUST provide more info. If you don't know any of these facts about your project then A) you won't get a helpful answer on SO and B) You're already putting the cart before the horse and must reconnect with the client or product manager for more pertinent information.

Comment: If I had to guess, this will be solved server side, which sounds like PHP in your case. Its not always the case, but generally speaking, if you are wanting to save files to your **server**, then you need to implement that on the **server** in whatever serverside language you are using.

Comment: It is possible with Cams MFS100 fingerprint scanner which supports the javascript api. Here is the device link https://camsunit.com/product/javascript-supported-biometric-fingerprint-scanner-CAMS-MFS100-A.html

Answer (score 12):

Welcome to 2019
You can now implement Web_Authentication_API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Authentication_API

Answer (score 10):

Firstly let me explain you the basic concept. For any external devices to interact , you need a device driver in the PC and a software that co-ordinates with the device driver to receive input and send outputs to the device.

You cannot do that with the sole HTML/JS alone.Also PHP is meant meant only for server side.

If possible your SDK/software supports uploading to internet, you can post & verify the data from the internet using PHP server.

If you prefer to go with JAVA, you can refer the below post:
[How to capture biometric information on a webpage by using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886411/how-to-capture-biometric-information-on-a-webpage-by-using-java)

Comment: This is no longer the correct answer as Web Authn now exists :)

Answer (score 2):

The [WebAuthn](https://webauthn.guide/) is the newest browsers feature that helps you to Authenticate users by Fingerprint Biometric on Mobile devices and Security devices on Desktop devices.