# How to add finger print scanner device with Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, fingerprint

How can I integrate a biometric fingerprint reader machine with my rails application, for the Voting System?

Comment: You need js for that - this is a browser action, not the server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167117/are-there-any-ways-to-integrate-fingerprint-biometrics-on-html5-or-javascript

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not reasonably scoped. It would require a lengthy tutorial or even a book as an answer.